# Failed to connect to AWS instance in Winscp . But works for PuTTY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, winscp

I am able to connect to AWS Linux 2023 instance using PuTTY.

When connecting using WINSCP Site information getting error:

Server refused our key.
Authentication failed.

From WinSCP I can press Ctrl+P and it opens PuTTY properly. That indicates that connection info is valid.

How can i connect winscp in aws server.

[image]

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Since it works with PuTTY, the network configuration is fine. The error is saying that the keypair you provided is not valid.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you have said that the key pair is not valid but it open in putty. The same key pair is working for putty and winscp in past days. So whats wrong in the key pair.

Comment: One of the following is happening in WinSCP: It is using a different username, a different keypair or a different target (IP / DNS Name). Please note that PuTTY uses a different format (.ppk) for keypairs than every other SSH tool (.pem). You can convert .ppk to .pem using PUTTYgen.

Comment: how can i look the session log?

Comment: Logging can be enabled on Options / Preferences but if you can't get to normal window because of the auth failure you can use commandline options, see https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#logging . @JohnRotenstein: WinSCP uses either OpenSSH (PEM) format _or_ PPK -- or instead of any file the Pageant process (the Putty version of ssh-agent) which in turn uses PPK.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.  I have upgraded the winscp. My Problem  solved. Its the problem in winscp. Once i upgraded the problem solved..

Comment: this worth a thumbs up, I was using 2019 winscp trying to connect Amazon Linux 2023 and it fails, upgrading Winscp solved it instantly